# Log all outgoing connections from computer

Tags: networking, windows-8, wireless-networking, router

I'm really interested in what applications on my PC sends to the internet. Is there any way to record all(!) outgoing data (including content - what is sent using that connection)? Ideally, these records would be stored in database / files containing things like what port it uses on my side, what ip:port it points to, time connection is opened and closed and what it sends. Is it possible (and reliable)?

I'm running windows 8.1, have access to my wireless router.

---

Edit: Logs don't have to be extra user friendly. I'm programmer.

Comment: https://www.wireshark.org/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to truly l log **all** traffic include traffic that might be hidden through a rootkit or other evil doer program you need to do it externally.  If your wifi router had a alternative firmware like openwrt or tomato then you could run tcpdump on it and forward the results either back to your computer or to another computer. Depending on the firmware you might be able to use file sharing such as CIFS or samba.

tcpdump -i eth0 -s 2000 -w outfile

OR

tcpdump -i eth0 -s 2000 -A

Note:  This can easily generate GB or TB of logs depending on surfing habits.

I setup a PC to act as a firewall with 2 nics and put a switch on the internal network so I could have multiple devices.  Given the nature of the internet even logging slightly suspicious traffic generates vast log files.

Since your a programmer you could write a program that utilizes libpcap and libmysql to directly log to a mysql database.

Another program to monitor suspicious traffic is **snort**